# Unable to move windows to second screen

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, compiz, xorg, multiple-monitors

Hooked up a second screen to the second connector of my nVidia card, set it up with `nvidia-settings` and it started showing my background correctly.

The X display works correctly (i.e. `DISPLAY=:0.1 gedit` works) and the cursor goes from one screen to the other but I can't grab windows to the second screen and windows on the edge doesn't appear half on one screen and half on the other.

The second monitor doesn't show in the monitor Ubuntu settings dialog.

I used to use the cube Compiz effect, but I am not interested in it anymore.

Tried rebooting. Any help appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Enable Xinerama in the Nvidia settings application and reboot. When you enable "use separate x session for each monitor", you can't move windows from one monitor to the other without enabling Xinerama too. Also, when using the Nvidia drivers, do everything from the Nvidia settings application, instead of the Ubuntu "Displays" dialog.

Comment: Worked, but lost compositing and Compiz segfaults... Any idea? Also, the resolutions dropdown in nvidia-settings lost all the options excepting Auto at one point that I can't recall.

Comment: Try rerunning `sudo nvidia-xsettings` and rebooting.

Comment: You meant nvidia-xconfig or nvidia-settings? Anyway, no luck.

Comment: Yeah, I meant nvidia-xconfig. I'm not sure then...

Comment: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/?id=84a14fab8f930ef1855444ae4e9e3e14ee008328 they are compatible only since X 1.10